# Error: Lost connection to MySQL en Servidor

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Tengo un problema con una consulta a mysql en php, estoy intentando ejecutar una consulta desde php a mysql en mi servidor, es una consulta simple, es un "DELETE FROM temp_sku", estoy intentando ejecutar esta consulta con un procedimiento almacenado pero me da el siguiente error:

> Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2013 Lost
> connection to MySQL server during query

Entiendo que este error es como si se superara el tiempo de conexión o algo similar, el problema es que este DELETE realmente no pesa nada solo es una tabla con una sola columna que almacena sku's por lo cual no pesa en absoluto.

Mi conexión la creo de la siguiente forma:

```
try{
            $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME,DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD,
            array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
            $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch (PDOException $e){
            $error = $e->getMessage();
            exit("Error: " . $e->getMessage());
        }
```

he intentado cambiar mi consulta y no usar un procedimiento almacenado, la he cambiado a esta forma:

```
$stmt = $connect->prepare("DELETE FROM temp_sku");
$stmt->execute();
```

Pero sigo recibiendo el mismo error. No entiendo que puedo estar haciendo mal.

Comment: ¿Te pasa solo con esa consulta? ¿Cuántos registros tienes en la tabla? ¿Quieres borrarlos todos? Si es el caso, probablemente te convenga usar `TRUNCATE TABLE temp_sku` para vaciar la tabla. Revisa el manual de [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-lost-connection.html) para ver si identificas alguna de las causas y con eso podríamos ayudarte.

Comment: Estuve consultando y me encuentro con que el uso de DELETE sin condición WHERE opera similar a TRUNCATE **pero tiene problemas de rendimiento** de modo que con seguridad tuviste TIMEOUT consulta [DELETE statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html) Sólo si pones la condición LIMIT su efecto será distinto en términos de borrado.

Comment: @Triby si de hecho ya di con el error, ammm esa consulta de DELETE se ejecuta despues de que le pido a prestashop que me cargue la lista de productos en una BD, solo le pido los SKU pero al parecer es lo que le toma tiempo, no se porque tarda tanto en consultar la lista de productos actuales de prestashop, puesto que estan conviviendo en el mismo servidor

Comment: @quevedo Entonces deberia usar TRUNCATE? el problema es que una consulta en prestashop se consume todo el tiempo y como estoy en un servidor compartido no puedo moficiar el max_execution de mysql

Comment: Eso te pensaba sugerir: Intenta con TRUNCATE y verifica qué pasa. Supongo que si como dices la tabla sólo tiene una columna, no te tomaste la molestia de definir claves primarias y eso podría ralentizar el DELETE

Comment: @quevedo si de echo si tiene claves primarias y auto incrementables el problema es que prestashop es el que tarda en ejecutar la consulta de los productos por eso se cierra la conexion.

Comment: Sugerencia: crea un webwork (es asíncrono) que ejecute las consultas a prestashop en segundo plano. Cuando las complete, actualiza un flag y en respuesta a esa actualización lanzas el DELETE ver [Web Workers API](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API)

Comment: @quevedo creo ya lo resolvi, lo unico que me interesa consultar ahorita son los SKU de los productos que estan en prestashop entonces lo que hice fue unicamente hacer la consulta de las referencias, asi no me traigo todos los datos y ya con eso funciona mucho mas rapido, el problema es que mi script de php despues de un tiempo detiene la ejecucion, no muestra error solo es como si terminara pero aun no termina.

Comment: Por favor muestra el script que se congela. Para poder revisarlo. Y, ponle un **finally** al try de modo que puedas mostrar algo o cerrar explícitamente la conn luego de terminar la consulta.

Comment: @quevedo intente postear el script pero esta muy largo para publicarlo, te lo dejo en esta url si te parece bien, https://www.dropbox.com/s/1lo049m2d1bff1q/script.php?dl=0

Comment: Hola acabo de darle una primera mirada. Todavía no veo algo que "dispare mis alarmas" para sugerir algo, salvo que al cerrar el archivo tiene la marca de cierre `?>` de php que está contraindicada para archivos de scripts porque **lanza encabezados** y puede provocar comportamientos extraños. ¿la estás usando o simplemente la agregaste para mostrar el fin del script?

Comment: @quevedo no de hecho la coloque porque tenia entendido que debia colocarla siempre para cerrar archivos php.

Comment: En ese caso quita esa marca. Adicionalmente, la clase **ModeloInsertarProducto** sólo contiene métodos estáticos, de modo que no piensas instanciarla. Declárala como **abstract class**.

Comment: @quevedo ok, hare lo que me dices, por otro lado si ejecuto este archivo en cron, es posible que no tenga problemas con que se pause la ejecución después de ciertos minutos?

Comment: Lo ignoro. Suelo usar otros mecanismos para ejecutar cosas que irían a cron